# Specify Python 2.7+ and Python 3.xx (any) in ``setup.py''

Tags: python, version, setup.py

My "`setup.py`" currently includes the following statement:

```
setup(...
    classifiers = [
            ...
            "Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7",
            "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
            "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.1",
            "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.2",
            "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.3",
            "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4",
            "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5",
            "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6",
            "Programming Language :: Python",
            ...
            ],
    ...
    )
```

Is there a way for me to specify "any Python 3, from 3.0 upwards", without explicitly enumerating all the existing and future Pythons?

The reason I ask this is because, even though the general "Programming Language :: Python :: 3" is specified in the above, an Anaconda install fails with:

```
Fetching package metadata ......... 
Solving package specifications: .... 
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:  
- dendropy 
- python 3.5
* Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package
```

The `pip` install works fine.

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with `"Programming Language :: Python :: 3"`?

Comment: As you can see from the example, I included that in the specification. But, for e.g., Anaconda fails to install this package under Python 3.5 without me explicitly including the "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5" statement.

Comment: I don't think `pip` or `conda` explicitly check the specific version classifier. I had no trouble installing packages only including the `"Programming Language :: Python"` specifier. Do you have a reproducible example when and how it doesn't work?

Comment: Without the "3.5" specification line, the conda install fails with ``vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ conda install -c ericmjl dendropy
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: ....
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - dendropy
  - python 3.5*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.``

Comment: That doesn't depend on the classifiers but on the versions the package was built against: https://anaconda.org/ericmjl/dendropy/files (no py35 builds avaiable for linux). Try `pip install dendropy`.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks! If you can make your comment(s) an answer, I would be happy to accept it as solving my question. I will edit my question to reflect the actual problem better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classifiers are just hints, neither `conda install` or `pip install` actually looks at them when you install a package. 
These hints are for the people searching for a package or looking at a package. If a package supports all python 3 versions it doesn't matter if you list them explicitly or just as `"Programming Language :: Python :: 3"` I guess most visitors will know what's meant - it's more a matter of personal preference of the author (and the number of already chosen classifiers).

However when you install the package with `conda` (even if it's pure python) it has to built against the python and OS version you're using. In your case you try to install from the [`ericmjl` conda channel](https://anaconda.org/ericmjl/dendropy/files). This channel contains the python 3.5 version but only for OSX, the binaries for linux are python 3.4 only.

You could install it from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/DendroPy) into your conda environment by using pip: `pip install dendropy` (make sure you use the `pip` that's installed in your conda environment).