# Is there any other way to upload package to PyPI?

Tags: python, pip, package, pypi, twine

I tried so many times and nothing seems to work even after I created a GitHub repo I can't upload my first package to PyPI every time I try to use twine it gives this

> C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\Python Packages\opencvFPS>twine upload dist/*
> Upl
> oading distributions to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/ Enter your
> username: Prathamesh_Bhatkar Enter your password:
>
> Uploading opencvFPS-0.1.tar.gz
>
> 100%|████████████████████████████████████| 5.26k/5.26k [00:02<00:00, 2.51kB/s]

> NOTE: Try --verbose to see response content.

And this error

> HTTPError: 400 Bad Request from https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
> Invalid value for classifiers. Error: Classifier 'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8.6' is not a valid classifier.

How can I solve this?

And I am new to PyPI so I Don't know much about it.

**Thanks!!**

Comment: And what does "twine upload dist / * --verbose" return?

Comment: It returns 
'Using configuration from C:\Users\Admin/.pypirc

Uploading distributions to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/

InvalidDistribution: Unknown distribution format: 'dist''

Comment: This is the complete list of allowed trove classifiers: https://pypi.org/classifiers/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove the minor python version in the classifier like the example mentionned in the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html).

So change it like this :

```py
setup(...,
      classifiers=[
          # Other classifier
          'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
          # Other classifier
          ],
      )
```

Comment: It works but why the python version was causing  the issue.

Comment: I'm no sure but I think it's because of the minor version is no supported or maybe I'm wrong. But like mentionned in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/41651584/5527968 it doesn't matter if it's specified or not.